# UITableView suddenly not retrieving data from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

This was working fine yesterday and without touching anything it stopped working today. When I run the query to allocate my 'filterEvents' array, 'objects' in the block is empty. Anyone know what's going on?

```
#import "FilterViewController.h"

@interface FilterViewController ()
@end

@implementation FilterViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.filterTable.dataSource = self;
    self.filterTable.delegate = self;
    [self performSelector:@selector(retrieveFilteredEvents)];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.filterEvents count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"filterTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


     NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.filterEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    self.eventTitle = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventType"];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.eventTitle;

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *tempDict = [self.filterEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *string = [tempDict objectForKey:@"eventType"];

    [self.delegate setFilter:string];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateParent" object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - Helper Methods

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)retrieveFilteredEvents
{
    PFQuery *retrieveEvents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"eventTypes"];
    [retrieveEvents orderByAscending:@"eventOrder"];
    [retrieveEvents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.filterEvents = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.filterEvents);
        }
        [self.filterTable reloadData];
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Parse was down today for a while. Maybe this is the issue?

Comment: According to status.parse.com everything seems fine. Also, my other test apps are working fine.

Comment: SOLVED. For whatever reason my keys in the app delegate were incorrect. I have no idea why as I haven't touched those files in a while but that was the issue.